# How to check if JComboBox is empty?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am not able to check whether the `JComboBox` is empty. The below code is not working.

```
if (t_m_priority.getSelectedItem() != null &&
t_m_priority.getSelectedItem().equals("SELECT")){
        msg = "Triage Time Is Not Entered";
        saveflag = false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: To check jcombobox getselecteditem is "null" .

Comment: So, whats wrong with `t_m_priority.getSelectedItem() == null`?

Comment: Well, without a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem there is no way we can possible know what the problem might be...(ps, that's worked really well for me for the past 15+ years)...

Answer (score 3):

`JComboBox#getSelectedItem` will return `null` when no items are selected

You could use something like...

```
if (t_m_priority.getSelectedItem() != null &&
    t_m_priority.getSelectedItem().equals("SELECT")) {
```

To first check to see if the anything is selected and then test to see what the selected item actually is...

Answer (score 0):

> JComboBox.getItemCount()

If this method returns 0, the component is empty.

```
if (t_m_priority.getItemCount() == 0) {
   msg = "Triage Time Is Not Entered";
   saveflag = false; 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
 Try this to check if no item is selected in the combo box.

```
if(t_m_priority.getSelectedItem() == null ) {
     msg = "Triage Time Is Not Entered";
     saveflag = false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the dummy item "Select" to the combo box, use a custom renderer to display "Select" when no item is actually selected. Then you can just check if the selected index of the combo box is not -1.

Check out [Combo Box Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/combo-box-prompt/) for a renderer that implements this functionality for you.